# Morphia model for serializing HTTP Request in MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, schema, morphia

I am basically working on creating a restful API which produces surveys and consumes survey responses.

I want to use Morphia library for modelling the HTTP Request document in MongoDB.

I want to log incoming HTTP request data for a survey application and later planning to analyze the data by performing various kind of "rule matching" on that request data.

HTTP requests have a quite a lot of information in headers. I want to basically store those headers in a meaningful way.

There are some standard headers with specific values, and there are some custom headers with custom values. I want to treat standard headers like Referer,Cookie,URL etc as first class citizens for query the data later.

I am not intending to store request body in this model as it will have a variable size ranging from body of KiBs to many MiBs.

So following are kind of queries i'll be performing

- Match HTTP Requests with Referer as major search engines. Match HTTP
- Match requests where URL param is some kind of regex Match HTTP Request
- Match requests where some Cookie and it's given value is present
- and list goes on..

What should a Morhpia model look like to achieve I described above ?

Morphia : http://code.google.com/p/morphia/

Comment: What have you already tried?